# Question on Functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} ^m$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having trouble solving this problem:

1. Let $\bar{x_1} = x_1 \cos(x_2)$ and $ \bar{x_2} = x_1 \sin(x_2)$
   Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ is a smooth function of $\bar{x_1}$ and $\bar{x_2}.$ Show that: $(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial\bar{x_1}})^2+(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial\bar{x_2}})^2 = (\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_1}})^2+ \frac{1}{x_1^2}(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}})^2$.

My Solution:
Using the Chain Rule: $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_1}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{x_1}}} \frac{\partial{\bar{x_1}}}{\partial{x_1}}  + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{x_2}}}\frac{\partial{\bar{x_2}}}{\partial{x_1}}$
 and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_2}} = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{x_1}}} \frac{\partial{\bar{x_1}}}{\partial{x_2}}  + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{x_2}}}\frac{\partial{\bar{x_2}}}{\partial{x_2}}$

I can get $\frac{\partial{\bar{x_1}}}{\partial{x_1}} = \cos{x_2}$ and $\frac{\partial{\bar{x_2}}}{\partial{x_1}}=  \sin{x_2}$ and $\frac{\partial{\bar{x_1}}}{\partial{x_2}} = -x_{1}\sin{x_2}$ and $\frac{\partial{\bar{x_2}}}{\partial{x_2}} = x_{1}\cos{x_2}$

But I don't know what else to do; more specifically, I don't know how I am supposed to take the partial derivatives when I don't have the function $f$. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically got the answer here. You have
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\partial_{x_{1}}f = \cos x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f + \sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f\\
\partial_{x_{2}}f = -x_{1}\sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f + x_{1}\cos x_{2} \partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f. 
\end{equation}
Compute $(\partial_{x_{1}}f)^{2} + \frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}}(\partial_{x_{2}}f)^{2}$ and see what you get.

Edit: $(\partial_{x_{1}}f)^{2} = \cos^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f)^{2} + \sin^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f)^{2} + 2\cos x_{2}\sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f$.
You can compute $\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}}(\partial_{x_{2}}f)^{2}$ similarly and then add them. You don't need to compute explicit partials of some specific function. In this case, you only need to know how the partials relate, which the chain rule tells you.

Edit 2: From the application of the chain rule that you included in your question we get $(*)$. This implies that
$$(\partial_{x_{1}}f)^{2} = (\cos x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f + \sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f)^{2} = \cos^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f)^{2} + \sin^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f)^{2} + 2\cos x_{2}\sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f.$$
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}}(\partial_{x_{2}}f)^{2} &= \frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}}(x_{1}^{2}\sin^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f)^{2} + x_{1}^{2}\cos^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f)^{2} - 2 x_{1}^{2}\cos x_{2}\sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f)\\
&= \sin^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f)^{2} + \cos^{2}x_{2}(\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f)^{2} - 2\cos x_{2}\sin x_{2}\partial_{\overline{x}_{1}}f\partial_{\overline{x}_{2}}f.
\end{align*}
Now if you add the above expressions together and simplify just a bit you should get the desired equality.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was a little unclear, what you told me to compute is what I'm having trouble computing. And once I get that computation, how can I see if it equals the LHS

Comment: I edited my answer to show one of the computations. Once you compute the other term and add them you should get the LHS. Do you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if this question is too simple but I'm looking at one of your computations and I'm wondering how you did this, did you use the chain rule? Did you square it first and then do the chain rule? And once I do the second computation will I have to do the computations on the LHS and see that they are equal?

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining everything clearly, I understand what to do for these problems now.

Comment: I added a second edit with a bit more detail that should address your questions. No, you won't need to do any further computations to confirm that they're equal.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Just a question: Why don't I need to do the LHS and show that they are equal? Also, maybe a more general question that would need to be answered in a different thread but what is the point of showing the two inequalities hold?

Comment: You've started at the RHS. You applied the chain rule, did some algebraic manipulations and got the LHS (maintaining equality at each step). This shows that they are equal and so nothing further is required. In general, since equality is an equivalence relation we have $RHS=LHS$ implies $LHS=RHS$ (i.e., = is symmetric).

Comment: As to the purpose, I'm not entirely sure what your instructor had in mind. It seems likely that's it's an exercise to practice applying the multivariable chain rule which has all kinds of important applications.